# Dual Space and Bidual

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, category-theory, dual-spaces

Definition: Let $x\in V$ then define the map $\hat{x}$ $:$ $V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ to be such that $\hat{x}(f)=f(x)$.

Definition: Define $a_V : V \rightarrow V^{**}$ to be such that $a_V(v)=\hat{v}$.

If $T:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear map, its bidual map is denoted as $T^{**} : V^{**}\rightarrow W^{**}$

Remark: The above maps are both linear transformations, and $a_v$ is an isomorphism between the space and its bidual.

Let $T: V\rightarrow W$ be a linear map. Show that if $V,W$ are finite dimensions, then $T^{**}=T$

Observations: Let $\{$ $v_1,v_2....,v_n$ $\}$ and $\{$ $w_1,w_2....,w_m$ $\}$ be basis of $V$ and $W$ respectively. Observe that $T^{**} \circ a_V= a_W \circ T$ ( I have verified this). I know that I must define the unique linear map that is determined by the basis to show that they are equal, what must that map be?

Comment: You don't have to define anything. You just have to verify that identity of maps.

Comment: @amsmath I have verified the identity, but why does it mean that $T^{**}=T$?

Comment: @amsmath if V is finite dimensional is it the case that $V=V^{**}$?

Comment: Oh ok. It is actually false that $T^{**} = T$ because $T : V\to W$ and $T^{**} : V^{**}\to W^{**}$. But they are similar because $T^{**} = a_W\circ T\circ a_V^{-1}$.

Comment: @amsmath even given the condition that $V,W$ are finite dimensional?

Comment: Of course because, e.g., $V$ and $V^{**}$ are different spaces. But they can be identified. The bijective linear map $a_V : V\to V^{**}$ deals as an idetifier between those two spaces. So if you identify $v\in V$ and $a_V(v)\in V^{**}$ (same for $W$ and $W^{**}$), you can write $a_V(v) = v$. If you do that, you get $T^{**}v = T^{**}a_V(v) = a_W(Tv) = Tv$ and hence $T^{**} = T$ in that sense.

Comment: @amsmath what do you mean by "identified"?

Comment: You have a bijective linear map $a_V$ from $V$ to $V^{**}$. That means that $V$ and $V^{**}$ are *essentially* the same space. They are called isomorphic, and $a_V$ is the isomorphism. So, you can identify $v\in V$ with $a_V(v)\in V^{**}$ and every $v^{**}\in V^{**}$ with $a_v^{-1}(v^{**})\in V$.

Comment: @amsmath as usual, you have been very helpful. Thank you very much and have a very wonderful day.

Comment: I have edited my last comment a bit. Thanks, dude.

Comment: One more: It's not only a bijective map, it's also linear. That means that the linear structure on $V^{**}$ is exactly the same as on $V$. With this I mean the following: take any two vectors $u$ and $v$ in $V$ and their identified elements $a_V(u)$ and $a_V(v)$ in $V^{**}$. Then the sum of the identified elements will be the identified element for $u+v$, because $a_V(u) + a_V(v) = a_V(u+v)$. So, $a_V$ keeps anything in the same order as it as before.

Comment: @amsmath I can only write $a_V(v)=v$ when $V=V^{**}$, right?

Comment: They will *never* be the same space! And $a_V(v) = v$ is also wrong. However, if you identify $V$ and $V^{**}$ and make your readers know that you do that, you can write $V = V^{**}$ and $a_V(v) = v$. It's called abuse of notation.